# Segmentation fault: 11 in C++ IntVector

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to implement an intvector in C++ and am getting a "Segmentation fault: 11" error. I understand this has something to do with memory management, and considering how new I am to C++ it could definitely be a pretty minor mistake. I debugged the code with valgrind and was given messages such as the following:

Use of uninitialized value of size 8, Invalid read of size 4,Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s).

My best guess is it has something to do with how I'm implementing the arrays. I originally had the arrays stored on the heap but changed it to the stack and still got the same error. I've already implemented an intvector in java, so I was attempting to use similar logic here, which perhaps is part of the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "IntVector.h" 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int num_elements = 0;
int array_size = 0;
int expansion_factor;

void IntVector::expandArray(){

   int tempArr[array_size*2];

  for(int i =0;i<array_size;i++){
    tempArr[i] = array[i]; 
  }

  array = tempArr;
  array_size = array_size * 2;

}
void IntVector::add(int val){

  int tempArr[array_size];

   if(array_size == num_elements){

     expandArray();
     array[num_elements] = val;    
   }
   else{
     for(int i = 0;i<array_size;i++){
       tempArr[i] = array[i];
     }
     tempArr[num_elements] = val;
     array = tempArr;
   }
   num_elements++;
}
void IntVector::remove(int index){   
  }
int IntVector::get(int index) const{
    return index;
  }
void IntVector::removeLast(){
  }
void IntVector::set(int index, int val){
  }

std::string IntVector::toString()const {
    return "";
  }

IntVector::IntVector(int initial_size){
  int* array = new int[initial_size];

  }

IntVector:: ~IntVector(){
  delete[] array;
}


int main(){

  IntVector v(0);
  v.add(5);
}
```

```
#ifndef INTVECTOR_H_
#define INTVECTOR_H_

using std::cout;
class IntVector {
private:
  int* array;
  int num_elements;
  int array_size;
  int expansion_factor;
  void expandArray();
 public:
  void add(int val);
  void remove(int index);
  int get(int index) const;
  void removeLast();
  void set(int index, int val);
  std::string toString() const;
  IntVector(int initial_size);
  ~IntVector();


};
#endif
```

Comment: `int tempArr[array_size*2];` -- This is not valid C++, unless `array_size` is changed to a `const int`.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  Also, why are you not simply using `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: `array = tempArr` makes the data member point to a local variable. Then the function returns, the local variable is destroyed, and `array` becomes a dangling pointer. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: *I've already implemented an intvector in java, so I was attempting to use similar logic here, which perhaps is part of the issue.* -- C++ is not Java.  Do not attempt to write C++ code using Java as a model.  Also, creating a working, functional, "IntVector" class is way more advanced than what you believe.  Your code has several major mistakes, where it seems you've taken Java code, and unfortunately, it happened to compile with the compiler you're using.

Comment: If you want to know what is to be done in C++ to create such a class, [see this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbd9033d9c94f6b3).  This isn't to scare you off, it is to show that it takes much more sophistication than lifting Java code, attempting to make it C++, compiling, and then hoping for the best.  Even the shown code may have bugs in it -- that's why you use `std::vector<int>`, and leave the creation of dynamic array classes to the expert programmers.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your response. I cannot use std::vector<int> because the assignment is to manually implement an int vector. We've only been learning c++ for about 2 weeks so I'm having a very rough time. I will take a look at the link, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in the comments, there are definitely some holes in your understanding of C++. Really when dealing with header files you should have a main.cpp, someotherfile.h, someotherfile.cpp. That just best practices to avoid redefinition errors.

There was quite a bit wrong with the way you accessed the private variable. If a class has a private( or even public) variable you don't have to redeclare it each time you want to change its value.

There were one or two major flaws with the way you expanded the vector. If the vector size is initialized to 0 then 0*2 is still 0 so you never actually increased the size. Secondly, when you set the original array = to the new array the new array was just a local array. This means that the memory wasn't actually allocated permanently, once the function ended the temparr was destroyed.

I know this was probably a lot but if you have any question feel free to ask.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "IntVector.h"

int main()
{
    IntVector v;
    IntVector x(10);

    v.push(5);
    v.push(5);
    v.push(5);
    v.push(5);
    v.push(5);
    v.print();
    cout << endl;

    x.push(5);
    x.push(5);
    x.push(5);
    x.push(5);
    x.push(5);
    x.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**IntVector.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntVector {
private:
    int *array;
    int num_elements;
    int array_size;
    //int expansion_factor =;  you would only need this if you plan on more than double the vector size 
    void expandArray();     //normally c++ array double in size each time they expand

public:
    //Constructors
    IntVector(); //this is a contructor for if nothing is called
    IntVector(int initial_size);

    //setters
    void push(int val);     //add   
    void pop();             //removelast
    void remove(int index); //remove
    void at(int index, int val);    //set

    //Getters
    int at(int index);
    //std::string toString(); I'm changing this to print
    void print();   //will print the contents to the terminal

    //Deconstructor
    ~IntVector();
};
```

**IntVector.cpp**

```
#include "IntVector.h"

//constructors
IntVector::IntVector() //no arguments given
{
    array = new int[0];
    num_elements = 0;
    array_size = 0;
}

IntVector::IntVector(int initial_size)
{
    array = new int[initial_size];
    num_elements = 0;
    array_size = initial_size;
}

void IntVector::expandArray()
{
    int *tempArr;
    if(array_size == 0){
        array_size = 1;
        tempArr = new int[1];
    } else {
        //make sure to allocate new memory
        //you were creating a local array which was destroy after the function was completed
        //using new will allow the array to exist outside the function
        tempArr = new int[array_size * 2];
    }



    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        tempArr[i] = array[i];
    }

    //make sure to delete the old array otherwise there is a memory leak.
    //c++ doesn't have a garbage collector
    delete[] array; 


    array = tempArr;
    array_size = array_size * 2;
}
void IntVector::push(int val)
{
    num_elements++;

    //checking if vector needs to increase
    if (array_size <= num_elements)
    {
        expandArray();
        array[num_elements-1] = val;
    }
    else
    {
        array[num_elements-1] = val;
    }

}
void IntVector::remove(int index)
{
    //not sure how to implment this becuase each element has to be a number.
}

int IntVector::at(int index)
{
    return array[index];
}

void IntVector::pop()
{
    num_elements = num_elements-1; //not really removing it from the "vector" but it won't print out again
}
void IntVector::at(int index, int val)
{
    array[index] = val;
}

void IntVector::print()
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}



IntVector::~IntVector()
{
    delete[] array;
}
```

**output**

```
5 5 5 5 5

5 5 5 5 5
```

Hopefully, the comments help. I changed the name of the functions to better match the actual vecter class the already exists in C++. I think it's good to pick apart already defined functions like this because you get a better understanding of how they actually work and not just how to use them.

If you got any questions just leave a comment

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out all day and this has helped me understand C++ more than anything else I've read! Thank you so much for putting so much time and effort into helping me out here, I greatly appreciate it!! Currently working through it but I will definitely let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: One question--why is it that you're using two constructors instead of just one?

Comment: This is called "overloading a function."  If you look that up you might find more information on it. Basically, if IntVerctor is called without an argument then the constructor without the parameter is executed. If IntVector is called with an argument then the constructor with a parameter is executed. This can be done with any function as long as the function has the same name and different parameters.

In this case, I added it because I wanted to initialize the vector differently (setting array_size=initial_size) depending on if the vector was initialized with some size.